# JavaScript: invalid quantifier when searching URL string for '?'

Tags: javascript

I just want to test the URL for a question mark ? however I keep getting an invalid quantifier error message...

```
alert(window.location.href.search('?'));
```

I then tried things like...

```
alert(window.location.href.search('\?'));
```

/

```
alert(window.location.href.search(\?));
```

...without any luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) converts the argument to a RegExp.`/?/` is an invalid RegExp. The escape does not work either, because a single backslash in the string is not converted to a RegExp-escaping backslash.

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead:

```
location.href.indexOf('?') !== -1; // If true, then found
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a RegExp pattern for the `"?"` to be found by `.search()`:

```
alert(window.location.href.search(/\?/));
```

Comment: Thanks, while client-side I'm less fanatical against using regex I'm going to use indexOf (been doing too much PHP of late). Still your code worked, thanks!

Comment: No problem. I may have as well post it just as a comment to your question, as it's not an answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually doubly-escaped `window.location.href.search('\\?')` will work